# Qualunque/qualsiasi con o senza pronome relativo?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

1. Ti darò qualunque/qualsiasi cosa tu voglia o che tu voglia?
2. Si fa suggestionare da qualsiasi/qualunque rumore potrebbe sentire o che potrebbe sentire durante la notte?
3. Chiamami, di qualunque/qualsiasi cosa tu abbia bisogno o di cui tu abbia bisogno?
4. Ci sarà sempre da ridire, in qualunque/qualsiasi modo tu lo faccia o in cui tu lo faccia?

In teoria dovrebbe essere corretta la seconda versione di ogni frase, ma a me suona sempre e solo la prima.

È solo una mia impressione o c'è una spiegazione grammaticale dietro?

Comment: Per curiosità, perché pensi che “In teoria dovrebbe essere corretta la seconda versione”? Quale teoria?

Comment: Comunque, credo che in nuce la risposta sia nel fatto che, [consultando un dizionario](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/qualunque), si vede che “qualunque” ha “funzione di indef[inito] **relativo**”.

Comment: @DaG Probabilmente dovresti scriverlo come risposta. Per essere più espliciti, *qualunque* e *qualsiasi* sono già pronomi relativi, non hanno bisogno di altri pronomi.

Comment: Sì, @DenisNardin, anche se in realtà non sono pronomi ma aggettivi, e c'è qualche distinzione da fare anche tra i due (c'è qualcosa in proposito sul Serianni). Purtroppo non ho tempo per dedicarmici; se tu o qualcun altro lo vuol fare, magari!

Comment: @DaG: intendevo che: "nel modo in cui", "quello che", quindi anche "in qualsiasi modo in cui", ",qualunque cosa che" ecc...